# Lightbox2 next arrow disappears after the first image of the group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have 3 pics that I want to link them in my photo gallery. So when I click one of the image, it should have the next and previous arrow that allow the user to go to another image. My codes with lightbox2 is as below.

```
<a href="my/path/images/image1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
<img src="my/path/thumbnails/thumb1.jpg" alt="Surfing"/>
</a>
<a href="my/path/images/image2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
<img src="my/path/thumbnails/thumb2.jpg" alt="Lifeguard Stand"/>
</a>
<a href="my/path/images/image3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="My caption">
<img src="my/path/thumbnails/thumb3.jpg" alt="Hot Air Balloons"/>
</a>
```

So now when I run the code, in the first image there will be an next arrow that links to the second image. However, when the user is in the second image, there is only previous arrow but no next arrow. But I want both arrows to appear.

If anyone knows how to solve the issue, please let me know. Appreciated!!

Comment: Could you setup snippet here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Umm pretty much my above codes is the snippet. Please note that it is written in html file only.

Comment: I can't reproduce problem, if user is on the second image, both arrows should appear. If you talk about third image in set, and if you want to set next arrow (to go to the first image, so, to cycle through images, after last image in set is reached), you need:  lightbox.option({
     
      'wrapAround': true
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer by myself and below is the answer for many people who may have encountered the same problems.

Just change the width of `.lb-nav a.lb-prev` in the `lightbox.css` and it should work. I change it from 64% to 50% and then the next arrow appears.

I don't have time digging into what's the essential cause is, but this solution does work. If anyone knows what exactly happens there, please feel free to leave a comment or answer. Appreciated!